# Does apache http framework work with libgdx for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, apache, libgdx

Does Apache http framework work with libgdx for Android and iOS?

I want to be able to make http request using Apache instead of libgdx's Java.Net code. Will it work (on both Android and iOS).

Comment: On Android it might work, since it seems to be supported (http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html). On iOS I'm not so sure. It would run via RoboVM in this case...

Comment: On the other hand, *why* do you not want to use libgdx's HTTP framework?

Comment: I want to use this api: 
https://github.com/gvsumasl/jacc/tree/master/java-channels-api

Comment: It seems RoboVM itself uses Apache http so it must work right?   https://github.com/robovm/robovm/tree/master/rt/external/apache-http/src/org/apache/http